# Outdoor fairy lights

Tags: solar-cell

Our outdoor solar lights stopped working due to water ingress.
I want to keep the lights but dispose of the solar panel making the lights "ordinary" battery powered. I've connected the lights to a 3.7v rechargeable battery but only every other light comes on.

When I turn the battery around the other lights come on and the first ones don't. How can I fix this so I can just have battery operated lights where all lights illuminate? I think the lights are LEDs, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The behavior you describe suggests the there's more to this "solar panel" than just a panel which charges a battery. It must have some extra electronics inside which generates AC power for the string of lights.

Answer (score 2):

The LEDs are wired in 'anti-parallel', which is a fairly standard feature for such lights. This allows you to have two independently lit strings of lights, which allows some reasonably convincing flashing and fading from one to the other.

Unfortunately, this means you will have to drive the LEDs with AC if you want all the lamps alight. Generating AC is straightforward with a bit of logic, but you will probably need discrete devices to be able to drive enough current into your LEDs. Ideally you will current-drive the LEDs, especially if you are going to drive them from a 3.7 V cell, whose voltage can vary from 4.2 V down to 3 ish.